# How to override javascript method and call from class?

Tags: javascript, events, triggers

Excuse the title but I'm not really sure what this is called (Maybe events?):

I have created a class that someone will use:

```
function cls_something()
{
    this.notify('hello');
}
```

Now the person using my class creates a method called 'notify' (as instructed by me) in order to listen for notifications and then perform their own custom code using the param I pass:

```
var something = new cls_something();

something.notify = function(message)
{
    console.log('The notification is ' + message);   
}
```

How do I call this method from within the class to give him the notification message?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzuev/)

I'm trying to achieve something like this...

```
websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:10000"); 

websocket.onopen = function(e)
{
    console.log('you are connected');
}

websocket.onmessage = function(e)
{
    console.log('omg wtf ffs, there was an error: ' + e.msg);
}
```

Comment: this.notify("blarg");

Comment: using this.notify('hello'); gives Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Did you write the WebSocket class? If so, then you need to call websocket.onopen() from within that class, when the socket is opened. If your websocket is opened straight from the constructor, then it has to be passed in as a parameter.

Comment: This is using the standard websocket built into the browser. It connects as soon as you create the object yet your methods come after the connect code. I assume the actual code has some kind of delay to read these in. Thanks for the help. You have basically answered my question. The methods I have added aren't available in the constructor. Will add a init() or connect() function after the custom methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call this.notify("Message"); You'd probably want to check to see if it's defined first, though.

EDIT 1:

Ok, so your problem here is that you're calling a function straight from the constructor, before it's defined. If it needs to be defined in the constructor, then pass the function as a parameter.

```
function cls_something(notifyFunction)
{
    notifyFunction('hello');
}
```

EDIT 2:

Just so we're clear, you can have the user of your class define functions later, if you'd like. You just can't run them straight from the constructor, obviously. If you run them from the constructor, they need to be defined before hand.

Say your class was something like

```
function cls_something()
{
    this.someFunctionThatIsRunLater = function() {
        this.notify('hello');
    }
}
```

Then your client can write

```
var something = new cls_something();

something.notify = function(message)
{
    console.log('The notification is ' + message);   
}
```

Then, when the client calls

```
something.someFunctionThatIsRunLater();
```

Notify will be called.

Comment: using this.notify('hello'); gives Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: That's why I said "You'd probably want to check to see if it's defined first". If the user of the class doesn't define something.notify (Like you said they would), then it's not going to be defined.

Comment: Can you update the original question with where the notify function is actually being called please?

Comment: @letslogic.com Edited your fiddle and updated the answer

Comment: What happens if there are +/-50 functions?

Comment: If the user has to define those functions, and you need them in the constructor, then there's no way around it. They have to be defined before the constructor runs. I have a feeling this isn't what you really need though. Why do you need to run these functions in the constructor?